# Do not display Blackberry icon on the Blackberry home screen for JDK

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am doing an application on Blackberry JDK. I want to use an option available for eclipse plugin saying **"Do not display Blackberry icon on the Blackberry home screen"**.

How can I find this option for JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark the application as System Module.

In fact, what the eclipse plugin does is exactly that. If you manually open an eclipse project descriptor (the xml file), you can read it:

```
IsSystemModule="true"
```